# Switching off captions

Tags: beamer, captions

Is there a way to make a LaTeX document switch off the captions in figures/tables?

I am using figures/tables with captions in a paper. Each was generated automatically by MATLAB and I use the `\input` command to include each. For my presentation (using `beamer`), I want to use the same files excluding the captions.

Comment: If you want to have no caption at all, maybe try `\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\relax}`.

Comment: you don't need any captions in beamer just type it under it

Comment: Just for typing less: `\def\caption#1{}`

Comment: @Bernard what is the purpose of `\relax` here (i.e. why not `\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{}`)?

Comment: It's to be sure it does nothing. Just in case… Perhaps you're right, `{}` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppressing existing captions is really easy with beamer, you just have to redefine the corresponding template and set it to empty.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\setbeamertemplate{caption}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{bla bla}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will not work if the `caption` package is used, so something like `\captionsetup{textformat=empty}` is needed in this special case.

Answer (score 1):

The general use of `\caption` in `article` differs from that supplied by the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) as well as that provided by [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer). However, if one assumes you're using the same file in both, then one could probably accommodate *at most* a `\caption*[<contents>]{<caption>}` (that is, no overlay specification `<.>`) . For that, we can redefine `\caption` using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

```
\documentclass{article}

% Create a dummy figure file created by MATLAB
\begin{filecontents*}{matlab_figure.tex}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx,xparse}

\begin{document}

\input{matlab_figure}

% Void \caption functionality
\RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{s o m}{}

\input{matlab_figure}

\end{document}
```